# Не переведено [Edit removed during grace period] в списке правок в профиле

Tags: дефект, локализация, правки, профиль-участника

Не переведено `[Edit removed during grace period]` в списке правок в профиле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor?tab=activity&sort=revisions (правка от `2021-03-31 14:27:28Z`)

В списке правок в вопросе переведено как "Свежая правка отменена":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1264366/revisions

Comment: Вероятно, связанные [проблемы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362124/339911). Ещё хорошо бы ссылку добавить помимо картинок, это позволит потом быстро проверить, когда и если пофиксят.

Comment: Добавил ссылки (правда ссылка в профиль скорее всего быстро станет неактуальной, придется искать это сообщение среди других правок)

Comment: А я в свою очередь добавил обратную ссылку на этот вопрос в баг-репорте на MSE.

Comment: На сегодня все еще актуально: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VzAf.png

Comment: Оказывается, я уже репортил это на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323043/339911) в 2019 году :)